# How to match password and confirm password with regex validation for uppercase and number

Tags: javascript, html

I want to match password and confirm password also do the regex validation for minimum 8 chars,Atleast 1 capital char, And atleast 1 number, i have done code so far, in console regex matching is giving null.
Thanks in Advance

```js
var pass = $("#password").val();
var cpass = $("#cnfpassword").val();
var passformat = "/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/";

console.log(pass, cpass);
console.log(passformat.match(pass));
if (passformat.match(pass)) {
  console.log(pass.match(passformat));
  if (pass == cpass) {

    document.getElementById('alertmsg').innerHTML = "Password Matched!";
    // return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('alertmsg').innerHTML = "Password Did not match!";
    //     return false;
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById('alertmsg').innerHTML = "password must be at least 8 characters contain capital letters,and number!!!";
  // return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group mt-2">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" aria-describedby="password" placeholder="Enter a password" style="width: 80%; margin: auto;" required onkeyup="ValidatePassword()">
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-2">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cnfpassword" aria-describedby="cnfpassword" placeholder="Repeat your password" style="width: 80%; margin: auto;" required onkeyup="ValidatePassword()">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of imposing complexity restrictions, ensure the length and entropy are high enough, e.g. with "zxcvbn". Remember the old saying, "Security at the expense of usability comes at the expense of security".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex for min 8 characters and contain at least 1 UPPERCASE, 1 lower case, 1 number, 1 special character

```
const myRegEx = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

myRegEx.test(password)
```

Comment: I have checked your solution it is returning false in console, even i have entered all the required characters..

Comment: myRegEx.test('USER@user28') Try this.

Comment: It contains uppercase, lowercase, special character, numbers and length is more than 8 as well.

Comment: Thanks Mohib Arshi it worked now,  I didn't made the changes properly before i think

Answer (score 0):

You usage of `.match()` should be the other way round. It should run as follows:

```
console.log( pass.match( passformat ) )
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for more info.

Also, you're regex is in a string, which may not be picked up correctly. Try the regex without the quotes, like below:

```
var passformat = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/;
```

Comment: Are you sure your regex pattern is correct? If it does not match, it will return null everytime.

Comment: By the solution of @Mohib Arshi it is not returning null now, it is returning false

Comment: So there's two approaches to this. You can either match the password against a regex pattern, which is your current setup. Or with Mohib's answer, he's testing the password against a regex pattern with `.test()`, which works slightly differently to `.match()`